# Device node access permissions in Linux

Tags: android-ndk, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a char device driver for embedded android.
The device module, register itself as a char device, and a corresponding device node is created under `/dev`. The problem is that the access permissions for this device is for root, and I can't read it from android applications (JNI). I have to manually `chmod +r` the device before running the application. How can I decide the access permission of a dynamically created device node ?

Answer (score 1):

If your device registers itself using [udev](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html), which is the most likely case, then you can create a custom udev rule to [manage the permissions](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#ownership) on this device.

For example, this rule assigns rw-rw-rw- permissions to a device belonging to the USB vendor 0bb4:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Comment: it's not relevant to the question. this is how to enable adb communication between dev pc and android device.

Comment: Your original post does not mention anything about communication with the PC.  Might want to clarify that.