# AOSP device node access permissions

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, android-source

This is a similar post as [device-node-access-permissions-in-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219684/device-node-access-permissions-in-linux?rq=1) 6 years ago without an answer.

I have a device node at `/dev/magic-i2c` created using `misc_register()`, the problem is the default access permissions for this device node is for root, and cant be accessed by `AOSP` libraries. I tried adding `.mode = S_IRWXUGO` but no effect. How can I change the permission of this device node automatically during bootup?

Comment: you could look at init.rc file, which tipically includes startup sequence. You just need to find appropriate place and place chmod/chown commands there

Comment: For setting permissions in Android I believe you should look deeper at [SELinux](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/) and configure proper policy for access to your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your device to this file in AOSP :

```
{AOSP DIR}/system/core/rootdir/ueventd.rc
```

First Add your device then set UID/GID and access mode for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `chmod 660 /dev/magic-i2c` in "on boot" section or somewhere in init.rc file. You can add this in any section in init.rc depending on when you need the permission to be given.